MacOS Ventura/Sonoma no signal when null dereference
Ventura 13.2.1 M1
Sonoma 14.2.1 M2
In my app I have a signal handler. 
When testing it with null-dereference I see that in previous MacOs versions like Monterey 12.0 x86 the signal handler is called. However on my Silicon Ventura/Sonoma machines its not called. 
Tried with SIP enabled and disabled
So I created a binary with code:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int *ptr = nullptr; 
    std::cout << *ptr; // Dereference null pointer
    return 0;
}

Compiled it with:
g++ null.cpp -o null.bin

And executed it with and without sudo.
The app indeed crashes because of the null dereference (and core dump is created when SIP disabled)
However, no signal is recived. I am able to prove it with DTrace .
DTrace script:
#pragma D option quiet

proc:::signal-send
{
    @[execname, stringof(args[1]->pr_fname), args[2]] = count();
}

END
{
    printf("%20s %20s %12s %s\n",
        "SENDER", "RECIPIENT", "SIG", "COUNT");
    printa("%20s %20s %12d %@d\n", @);
}

Here is the output. In the left terminal I executed the binary. In the right terminal the script output.

On top of DTrace I created and MacOS endpoint-security app and subscribed to ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SIGNAL. Same there, no signal.
Did anything change with signals on M1/M2 MacOS 13.0 ?

It says "segmentation fault", so there is definitely a SIGSEGV somewhere. And if I install a signal handler with signal(SIGSEGV, ...), then I can catch NULL derefs, so I'd file this under "cant reproduce"...
